# DropdownListfor not selecting the value from the dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have gone through all the posted queries regarding this, but found no solution,This is the Controller
 Dont know where im going wrong`

```
string path = LibConf.dllAppSetting("graphcsvfiles");
System.IO.DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files  = d.GetFiles("*.csv");//Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(s => s.EndsWith("*.csv"));
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectLists = files.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.FullName });

MyTestModel m = new MyTestModel;
m.filenames = selectLists;
return View(m);
```

This is the model

```
[DisplayName("File")]
public string File { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> filenames {get; set;}
```

View:

```
 <td>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.File)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.File, new SelectList(Model.filenames, "Text", "Value"), "-select type-", new { @class = "css-class", @style = "margin-right:4px; width:150px;height:28px" })
  </td>
```

Comment: `m.File` does not appear to be populated so why would anything be selected in the dropdown?

Comment: @ErikPhilips.. Appologies, I am new to mvc. Please help what is to be done

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this code. 
Make sure you imported your model into view

```
 @model WebApplication.Models.MyTestModel 

<td>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.File)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.File, new SelectList(Model.filenames, "Text", "Value"), "-select type-", new { @class = "css-class", @style = "margin-right:4px; width:150px;height:28px" })
  </td>
```

Comment: Model is present in my view, and i am able to see the dopdown list but the problem is not able to select from the dropdown list

Comment: What happens when you click on a item? Is it showing "-select type-" always?

Comment: --select type-- is coming as option and when i click on it, nothing is happening

Comment: --select type is not coming in the textbox of the dropdown instead it is just showing like other options. Am i missing something with m.File

Comment: By default "--select type--" should be the selected item like this https://imgur.com/CUIGobG. And when you expand the list it should be shown like this https://imgur.com/rTGBeQb . --select type--  will be shown as an item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

After all the workaround, I observerved that @Html.DropDownListFor doesn't work properly inside "td".
Same code when kept outside the "td" is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why the dropdown list is not selecting the value is because you have never told what value it should select:

```
MyTestModel m = new MyTestModel();
m.FileNames = selectLists;
```

You've never assigned a value to the `m.File`, which is the selected value for the dropdown in this case. Hence the dropdown would only default to your option label.

You need to do:

```
MyTestModel vm = new MyTestModel
{
    File = "KEY_VALUE_THAT_IS_ON_THE_LIST",
    FileNames = selectLists
};

return View(vm);
```

Also I would like to correct 2 of your coding styles/problems, since you're pretty new to MVC:

#### 1. `@Html.DropDownListFor` doesn't work inside of `<td>`??

Nope. A dropdown / select is a valid element inside a table cell. See screenshot below.

[image]

#### 2. Your view model contains a select list already

You're constructing an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to the view model, and it's passed into `SelectList` on the view to render as a dropdown. The `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is **the** `SelectList`! You don't need to construct another one and pass your list of `SelectListItem` into it again.

Instead, you can just do:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.File)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.File, Model.FileNames, "- select type -" ... })
```

Comment: I did this but still was not working inside the html table

Comment: @Lax: then it might be something else that caused your problem. It's working on my end (proved by screenshots).